# IF / THEN coffee script links

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am learning coffee script... I have some code that defaults to a JS popup - but I also want to customize some of the links with mailto's and other content, and have the JS by default only if there is no primary direction

for example... if a user clicks on REQUEST ADMIN PRIVILEGES i want a mailto to popup NOT the JS that says "THIS FEATURE IS NOT YET AVAILABLE"

```
onPhotosLoaded = (sampledata) ->
            if !sampledata || sampledata?.success == false
                jvmw.empty().append('Gallery not found')
                return
            # once the photos are loaded
            jvu.waitCss $("#jv_mw"), 'jv-colorbox-css-loaded', ->
                $.colorbox.init()
                jvmw.empty()
                afterPhotosAndTags() # don't load tags before getting here.

                email = "#{gal_code}@phto.us"

                addMorePhotosInfoDiv = $ """<div/>""" 
                addMorePhotosButton = $ """<div style="float:left;font-size:32px"><br>Everyone's photos from "<span class="jvreplacewitheventname">this event</span>" <a class="jvaddmorephotosbutton" href="#">+Add yours!</a> <br/> </div>"""
                addMorePhotosInfoDiv.append addMorePhotosButton
                dragDropDiv = $ '<div class="jvdragzoneparent" />'
                addMorePhotosInfoDiv.append(dragDropDiv).append('<div style="clear:both;" />')
                extraTestButtons = $ '<div id="jvextratestbut" />'
                extraTestButtons.append('<a href="mailto:adminplease@albumpl.us">Request Admin Privileges</a> |  | <a href="#">Turn SMART BROWSE (ON)</a> | ' + 
                    ' | <a href="#">Purchase prints and other merchandise</a>|| <a href="http://www.albumpl.us/gallery/#{gal_code}/live">Live View</a>')

                extraTestButtons.find('a').click ->
            if $(this).text() == 'Request Admin Privileges'
            # <a href="mailto:adminplease@albumpl.us">Request Admin Privileges</a>
                 return false
            # default thing to do is show the dialog - and register the event.
                showNotYetAvailableMessage($(this).text())
     return false

    extraTestButtons.find('a').click ->
  if $(this).text() == 'Live View'
    # <a href="http://www.albumpl.us/gallery/#{gal_code}
            return false
  # default thing to do is show the dialog - and register the event.
          showNotYetAvailableMessage($(this).text())
         return false
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using way too much indentation, and worse, your comments are indented inconsistently with the code they correspond to. That's making your code very hard to read, and may even be tripping up the compiler—especially if you're using both tabs and spaces (don't do this!).

Instead of the current

```
if $(this).text() == 'Request Admin Privileges'
# <a href="mailto:adminplease@albumpl.us">Request Admin Privileges</a>
     return false
# default thing to do is show the dialog - and register the event.
    showNotYetAvailableMessage($(this).text())
```

just write

```
if $(this).text() == 'Request Admin Privileges'
  return false
showNotYetAvailableMessage($(this).text())
```

or even, using CoffeeScript's postfix conditionals,

```
return false if $(this).text() == 'Request Admin Privileges'
showNotYetAvailableMessage($(this).text())
```

Answer (score 3):

Wow.. If you choose coffee then write in its style.

Use its indentations style and some shugar like 'is', 'not', etc. Don't use extra syntax.

```
if $(this).text() is "Request Admin Privilegies"
  return false 
showNotYetAvailableMessage $(this).text()
```

Try to use approach that everything is expression and it returns something. It is useful for if..else, switch.. statements.

As for me, using style like

```
$ "div"
```

is awful :) and need some efforts to copypaste your code for example to jquery forum if you have some questions.

Other bad approach for jQuery is using

```
$(@)
```

instead of

```
$(this)
```

Coffee is Great! Use it right!